# Concatenate unique values from a column, but reset concatenation if any of the value already exists in the column using R programming

Tags: r, dplyr, concatenation, sequence

Here is a df

```r
id   name   
1    A  
1    B  
1    C   
1    A  
1    A  
2    C  
2    D
```

desired output with calculated column

```r
id   name calculated_column  
1    A    A,B,C  
1    B    A,B,C  
1    C    A,B,C  
1    A    A,B,C  
1    B    A,B,C  
1    C    A,B,C      
1    B    B,C    
1    C    B,C    
1    A    A  
1    A    A  
1    A    A  
2    C    C,D  
2    D    C,D
```

I thought I could maybe create a sequence column and do a concatenation, but I'm really stuck.
I want to use dplyr, but I'm open to other suggestions.

```r
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(calculated_column = ... ?)
```

Comment: Use `mutate(calculated_column = toString(unique(name)))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response <3 close. I just edited my question. So I want the concatenation to reset when a value from the name is dropped. For instance if A is not present anymore, I want just B and C to show up. There has to be some kind of reset concatenations based on previous values.

Comment: Can you pls explain why the reset happens in row 4 (when B appears a 2nd time) and in row 6 (when A appears a 2nd time), but not in row 5 (when C appears a 2nd time)?

Comment: @StatisticsTutorial your case is not clear.  Suppose for the ID 1, you have names as 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', what will be the output

Comment: Hello sorry for the confusion. So what I have in my mind is to create a sequence and group by as I progress forward. As you go down you notice A,B,C and then the second you see A again, there is a reset in the sequence. So A,B,C becomes a group. 
Then when you get to B,C - notice that A isn't there, so B,C becomes a new group. That new group has to be concatenated. Is it not possible to it like that?

Comment: I can get pretty darn close, the issue I have is it creates a group with "B,C,A", but this is a jumping off point I think ```library(dplyr)

df<-data.frame("id" = c(rep(1,11),2,2), "name" = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","B","C","A","A","A","C","D"))

df$New<-ave(df$id,df$name,FUN=seq_along)

df%>%
  group_by(id, New)%>%
  mutate("calculated_column" = paste0(name, collapse = ","))%>%
  select(-New)```

Comment: @silentdevildoll check out the solution to the guy who responded using data.table. But yea yours is close. thank you so much! I really appreciate it. And everyone else here. You guys are amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id = c(rep(1L, 11), rep(2L, 2)), nm = LETTERS[c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,3,1,1,1,3,4)])
dt[, grp := nm <= shift(nm, fill = Inf), by = id][, grp := cumsum(grp)][, calc := .(.(nm)), by = grp][, c("nm", "calc")]
#>     nm  calc
#>  1:  A A,B,C
#>  2:  B A,B,C
#>  3:  C A,B,C
#>  4:  A A,B,C
#>  5:  B A,B,C
#>  6:  C A,B,C
#>  7:  B   B,C
#>  8:  C   B,C
#>  9:  A     A
#> 10:  A     A
#> 11:  A     A
#> 12:  C   C,D
#> 13:  D   C,D
```

Comment: OH MY GOSH! You are a legend! I can't believe I get to see so many incredible minds here. Man, I was really breaking my head. I was hoping for a DPLYR solution, but yours works just fine. Thank you so much <3. And thanks a bunch for all the comments from others as well. You guys are pure brilliant.